# Very simple 1 input form value check

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

Haven't been coding in a bit, but took on a project for a friend.  Basically, I need a 1 input form that checks for a 4 digit code.  If the code is correct (is one of the 2 or 3 possible correct codes), it proceeds to a new page, if it's not it doesn't submit, and displays an error.  It doesn't have to be very pretty.  Looking for a jquery solution, and any push in the right direction would be appreciated.  I'm very rusty.

```
<form name="codeForm" action="" method="get">
     <input name="yourCode" type="text" id="yourCode"/>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Go" id="code_input_submit" />

    <div id="message"><p></p>
     </div><!--end message-->

</form>

<div id="btn"></div>
```

and my jquery is along the lines of the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var code1 = "7816";
var code2 = "1226";

$('#btn').click(function() {
var value = $('#yourCode').val();

    if (value == code1){                                             // go to site 'abc.com/'code1;
    }
      else if (value == code2){                                         //go to site 'abc.com/'code2;
    }
    else{                                      $('#message').html('your code is wrong');
    }
});

});
```

Comment: atleast post the html...

Comment: How do you get those correct code? Are they dynamic? Any limitation?

Comment: Sorry guys.  The "code" i was thinking would just be an array of 4 digit strings, or just 2 string variables that would be static.  Eventually I think I'll be using xml, but for now i was just going to define them inside the js file.

Comment: You seem to be asking for a way to validate the entered code within the browser before submitting, which means the correct codes will not be a secret: any user can see your JavaScript code via the browser's "View Source" option and/or various dev tools. Is that what you want to do?

Comment: nnnnn- check out my comment on Frankie's response.  This is a temporary solution to provide a visual walk-through to the client of what I have in mind.  No security risk right now. (although i will do something a bit more elegant in the future, there is still not anything to gain if they were to see those codes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is what it seams to be, a validation requirement and you're actually thinking of storing the data client side: **No, no, no!**

**Your "entry-pins" will be in plain sight of every single user trying to log on.**

You should always authenticate server side.

```
1. store the keys on server (database or file, whatever suits you)
2. client makes a request to server via post
3. Server accepts or denies client request
```

For example, submit the form to the server-side page `authenticate.php`

And PHP file will check if user is good to go or not.

```
<?php
// very simple and not really secure server-side auth script
$codes = {1234, 5678, 9012};
$valid_user = false; // all users are invalid until otherwise

$user_inserted_code = (int) $_POST['key'];
if(in_array($user_inserted_code, $codes)) {
    $valid_user = true;
}

if($valid_user==true)
     header("Location: http://example.com/authenticated");
else
     header("Location: http://example.com/failled_auth");
?>
```

**If you really don't need security and the codes you're refering to are static and something in the likes of (ie) department codes... growing on your example you can just use a simple switch:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var code1 = "7816";
    var code2 = "1226";

    $('#btn').click(function() {
        var value = $('#yourCode').val();

        switch(value) {
            case 7816: window.location = "http://google.com/"; break;
            case 1226: window.location = "http://yahoo.com"; break;
            default: $('#message').html('your code is wrong');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hey Frankie thanks for the response.  It's not really as much of a "validation" as it seems from the simple example.  There's NO security issues or really anything at all to gain if someone were to view these 2 codes.  It just brings them to an appropriate page to schedule an appointment.  Aside from that, right now we're just getting this started with the site and the purpose of this is for a non-live test run, just to give the client a "walk-through" of what the process looks like, so anything quick and dirty will be fine for now, and I'll improve later.

Comment: @Brian Battenfeld updated answer to include a small piece of JS that will do what you want...

Comment: thanks bud.  I'm diving into authenticating server side now that I have a bit of time to play, but thanks for the quick and dirty solution.  It's all coming back to me now ha.